# How to fix Error Code 401 when using requests

Tags: python, windows, python-requests

I want to apologize for my previous post. I realized I did not put any code so I deleted the post.

I am trying to use the `requests` module to access an SSRS database, while inputting the necessary username and password for authentication. The problem I am having is when I hard code the username and password, I am able to get error code 200 for the response. However, when I use the systems' username and password, I keep getting error code 401, even though the hardcoded and system information match. I would appreciate the help.

```
import os, time
import win32cred

username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
credential = win32cred.CredRead('domain\abc', win32cred.CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, 0) # domain\abc placeholder
password = credential.get('CredentialBlob').decode('utf-16')

from requests import Session
from requests_ntlm2 import HttpNtlmAuth
import ssl
session = Session()
response = session.get(url='https://something.com//Reports/report/Bill%20Of%20Material&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL', verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)

if response.status_code == 401:
    time.sleep(5)
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username=username, password=password)
    response = session.get(url='https://something.com/Reports/report/Bill%20Of%20Material&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL', verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
    print(response.status_code)    # keeps returning 401 when using system info
```

**UPDATE**

I now realized that I chose the wrong credential key, which was providing a different password than the one that is needed. This post can be disregarded.

Comment: " I realized I did not put any code so I deleted the post." Note can always **edit** the question to improve it, rather than deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Have you printed out `username` and `password` in this code to ensure that they're being read from the environment variables and credential store correctly?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, during debugging this, I printed the username and password and they're being read form the credential store correctly.